# Get first email from conversation id using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

Is it possible to query for the first, or all emails from a particular conversation id using the Microsoft Graph? If not, how about with the classic Exchange API?

**Scenario:** I am creating an application where I am interested in tracking the user who started an email thread, and the content of their initial message.

When querying for mail using the Microsoft Graph, I can get back an `id` unique to that email, and a `conversationId` unique to that email thread. The `body` returns the full email thread so far, but it is none trivial to parse (are there tips to parsing the returned HTML?), and may not always be accurate if people are adjusting the mail that gets sent back and forth.

Maybe the solution here is to parse the full `body` HTML, but I have not seen any documentation on best practices here. Any tips?

Answer (score 6):

To get all mails with same `conversationId`, you can use

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter= conversationId eq 'yourConversationId'
```

Microsoft Graph is using OData. So you can use query parameters to customize responses.

For how to use query, please check [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters).

Comment: Note that you should be logged (click on the button "Sign in with Microsoft") to be able to actually fetch your related mails. Else, the API will return an empty array as result. Might be obivous btw.

Comment: i got Invalid filter clause errors while executing this

Comment: 2020 and I still got invalid filter clause errors like above

Comment: If you're using the graph explorer you need to URL encode the conversationID. For example if it ends with a trailing `=` it becomes `%3D`. Confirmed just now that this works.